# Laravel Eloquent - "whereNotIn" using a subquery?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm struggling to figure out how I can use this SQL with eloquent methods.

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE artists.id NOT IN
(SELECT artist_id FROM artist_issues WHERE issue = 'update_images')
```

I see that the "whereNotIn" method takes a column, and then an array as the second parameter, so it's not possible to pass a subquery.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the correct relationships set, it should be something like this:

```
$artists = Artist::whereHas('artist_issues', function(q) {
   $q->where('issue', '<>', 'update_images');
});
```

I guess you have something like this in your `Artist` model:

```
public function artist_issues()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ArtistIssue');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so from what I can understand, the whereHas method creates a subquery in the where statement, but then what does the "<>" represent?

Comment: It's the operand "different of" of SQL.

Comment: Ah okay, I'm still not sure if this is the correct solution, we can forget about the where statement of the subquery for now. If I simply want to have a where statement like this - "WHERE NOT IN (SELECT artist_id FROM artist_issues)" then I don't see how a "whereHas" represents that in any way? 

Cheers!

Comment: That's the way of creating a JOIN, which, ultimately, is what you want to do.